# Why do all my products (in Ubercart) get taxes applied after upgrading my Rules module?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules, ubercart

I am using Drupal 7 and [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) (version 3). I try to add TAX to only certain items which has a particular Taxonomy Term Selected.

This functionality worked fine in previous version of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) 7-2.8  But now for some reason all rules conditions come back as true and VAT is applied on all products.

I have tried downloading the older version same issue.

How to Replicate:

- Configuration > Tax > Editing Condition Set VAT
- Entity has field (Parameter `order:product:0:node`) has Field Product_Type
- Data Comparison (Parameter `order:product:0:node:Product_Type`) one of Books, Hardware

So my real problem is that somehow all the products which do not have these terms selected are getting Taxes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please enhance your question to add the current version of Rules (where this issue occurs), and the version of Rules where this problem did not occur.. Also, just to check if the Rules version upgrade is the real cause of your problem, have you tried returning to the prior version of Rules, to confirm that the issue then indeed does not occur anymore?

Comment: Yes I ahve tried that too, previosu all the vesions till Rules 7.2-3 still occurring,

Answer (score 0):

Your comment about Rules version 7.x-2.3 rings a bell: I'm about sure that that is actually causing your problem. Refer to these issues for some more details:

- [Upgrading Rules from 2.3 to 2.6 brings white screen](https://www.drupal.org/node/2124597).
- [<7.x-2.4 breaks site with "Fatal error: Class 'RulesEventHandlerEntityBundle' not found"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2090511).

I've hit a similar issue some months ago (in an "old D7 site where Rules wasn't upgraded yet from a pre-7.x-2.3 version). After I upgraded to the most recent Rules version (7.x-2.9) my site was broken also. I don't remember what the actual error was, but I narrowed it down to this Rules upgrade issue.

The way I got around it was like so:

- **Uninstall** the 7.x-2.9 version of Rules (that I had ust upgraded to).
- **Re-install** (from scratch) the 7.x-2.9 version of Rules.

That solved "my" issue. And I'm pretty sure it will also solve yours ... wanna try it? Attention: backup any of your custom rules first. E.g via an "export" of those custom rules (before uninstall), and "import" again afterwards (after you upgraded).

PS: just in case anybody else ever looks at this answer before upgrading from a pre-7.x-2.4 version of Rules, you can avoid the above surprises when upgrading Rules to something like 7.x-2.9 by:

- first uninstalling the old version (after export of custom rules),
- and then installing the newest Rules version (and then import of custom rules).

Comment: Thanks Pierre, that was the first thing I did.  But his seems like a condition loop issue. If one items has the taxonomy term all other items of the order get taxed. It almost seems like the order total in getting vat  rather than the line items